# How to select a Column based on the Header value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I delete rows if a particular value is not found in a column.

Example Excel data:

```
Sl.No     Content
1         Apple
2         Ball
3         Cat
4         Ball
5         Cat
```

```vb
Sub Delete()

    Dim startrow As Long
    'starting row number here
    startrow = 2
    ' Assuming data to check is in A Column
    Do Until startrow > Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(startrow, 2).Value = "Ball" Then
            Rows(startrow).Delete
        Else
            startrow = startrow + 1
        End If
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

The output of this code:

```
Sl.No     Content
1         Apple
3         Cat
5         Cat
```

This code is working.

Now I am trying to select the B column using the column header 'Content' and then delete the rows containing 'Ball' instead of providing the cell number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Delete()

    Dim startrow As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    'starting row number here
    startrow = 2
    ' Assuming data to check is in A Column
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("Content", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Do Until startrow > Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(startrow, rng1.Column).Value = "Cat" Then
                Rows(startrow).Delete
            Else
                startrow = startrow + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "Column Not Found", vbCritical
    End If

End Sub
```